# wordwrap() the text and align center imagettftext()

Tags: php, imagettftext

I am working on gift card where the header fontsize is 100. If the header length more the 35 I want to wordwrap() that and display it in the new line.

In new line I want to display the text in center also.

Here is my code

```
$header=$_POST['headerdemo'];
$header = wordwrap($header, 35, "\n", true);
$headerbbox = imagettfbbox(100, 0, $font, $header);
$headerCenter = (imagesx($image) / 2) - (($headerbbox[2] - $headerbbox[0]) / 2);
imagettftext($image,100,0,$headerCenter,2100,$color,$font, $header);
```

In the abvoe code the headerCenter successfully center the text. It is OK for small lenth of text, but in case if wordwrap() thing happened the new **line start from the left.**

> I want the new line also to be in center.

Comment: I dont believe wordwrap is built-in.

Comment: Thanks for response do you have any alternative?

Comment: As a possible algorithm, you could progressively write each char in sequence to a separate "canvas", lets call this a "buffer". When the total width exceeds the limit, thats where you know when to either break by char, or when to backtrack in your loop to break by word. ... Centering can be done by centering these parts so discovered via the buffer.

Comment: I remember but do not recall the exact name of the function to determine the width of text rendered via gd. If such exists, you won't need the buffer.

Comment: can you please find the function? It is imagettfbbox?

Comment: Here's a good start. You can refine when you get there https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Comment: https://www.nrhtrauma.se/gavokort/

Comment: This is in live

Comment: I want to optimize Rubrik